# Android Native icon usage

Tags: android, icons, react-native

**React Native Framework**

In react native framework how can i use android native icons available in my android Application.Not clear documentation found. any help appreciated.

Comment: what do you mean by native icons? Can you give an example

Comment: drawable starts with '@android' schema. like '@android:drawable/btn_plus'